# iPad target uses iPhone app icon

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, asset-catalog

I have a project that contains two targets. One to build for iPhone and another to build for iPad. Each target has its deployment device set to the correct device type.

We then have two asset catalogs, each containing the app icons. One contains the iPhone app icons and the other, the iPad app icons. In the target General settings the correct asset catalog is selected for each target.

We have two `info.plist` files, one for each target, and this is also set correctly.

Now, when I build an archive for the iPad version, no icon is present. However, if I add the iPhone icon's to the iPad asset catalog then the icon appears (I presume its the iPhone one showing).

Why would this be if the target is set to iPad? Any ideas? I've been trying to fix this for almost 2 whole days now.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure the two things before archive the build.

1. You choose the correct target from tool bar 
2. You choose the correct target from target membership for the iPad assetcatalog.

[image][image]